# Why does Wide-sense stationarity imply Strict-Sense Stationarity in Gaussian Processes?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I read it in various references that the gaussian process will be also SSS ( Strict - Sense Stationary) if it is WSS because the pdf is just defined by the covariance matrix and the mean vector.

My main confusion is that, I agree there will no dependency on time of the nth order PDF caused by the mean vector but isn't the covariance matrix still dependent on time , ($t_{1} - t_{2}$ ).

To the extent to what I understand( which might be wrong), the dependency on time of the covariance matrix in the nth order PDF of a GP only eliminate if we assume that all the $t_{i}$ are consecutive.
So what is the actual explanation ?

Thanks For help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be missing the meaning of strict sense stationarity, which is that for any number of finite times, if you shift all those times by the *same* amount, the distribution is still the same. Thus, your strict sense stationarity definition also relies on the differences of times in a certain sense of the word

So, if the density $f$ only depends on $t_1 - t_2$, then since $t_1 - t_2 = (t_1 + \tau) - (t_2 + \tau)$, then you will have $f(t_1, t_2) = f(t_1 + \tau, t_2 + \tau)$ for any $\tau$.

Comment: Thanks I had the same question and came in looking for an answer like this.